# Headset Mic not working on Desktop

Tags: 14.04, microphone, headset

I have Philips SHE 3575 Wired Headset. The headphones are working fine. But there is only one jack, and the mic is not working. 
The options I see in Sound->Input are Rear Microphone and Front Microphone.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. ASUS SABERTOOTH Motherboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you've got a headset with a single jack that has 4 pins for both input and output (like smartphone headsets).

You need to use a splitter that splits the headset's cable into two jacks which you can plug appropriately into the computer.

I hope I get your question correctly.